# No new codecs in TeamViewer converter

Tags: windows, codec, video-codecs, teamviewer, ffdshow

Windows 8.1 x64

TeamViewer .tvs convert option:
https://snag.gy/uPAFTH.jpg
1. MJPEG Compressor
2. Cinepak Codec by Radius
3. Intel IYUV codec
4. Intel IYUV codec
5. Mircorosft RLE
6. Microsoft Video 1

only few ('windows standard') codecs list

I had installed K-Lite codecs pack. Also ffdshow codec separately. But with no result

Also msinfo32 shows only these codecs

What can I do to make new modern codecs available in those lists?

Video playing in different players just fine with any codecs needed